# Is Energy said to do work on the body it is stored in?

Tags: energy, work

Assume a boy on top of the hill, his $potential$ $energy=mgh$. He mostarts to move without pedalling the cycle so is that work being done on it due to the conversion of Potential into Kinetic Energy or Gravitational Force is doing the work?

Comment: As an aside, it is more correct to view potential energy as a property of a system (in this case the Earth-boy system) than of a single object. For PHYS101 purposes we often take the planet as assumed and use the rather sloppy language "the potential energy of the boy", but it's not the best way to frame things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is that work being done on it **due to the conversion of Potential into Kinetic Energy** or **Gravitational Force** is doing the work?

**Yes** to both statements.

The gravitational force is causing the conversion from potential to kinetic energy. A force is required for an energy conversion.